# run selenium script based on the trigger (ip address was changed) in Jenkins

Tags: events, selenium, jenkins, ping

all. I have been using Jenkins for a month for running Selenium scripts. Now i have a problem. I need to run Selenium script based on the event - if IP address of the server has been changed. Do you have any thoughts how can i do that with Jenkins?